# Difference between the APIs `aws s3` and `aws s3api` when granting permissions to a canonical ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In order to upload a file to an s3 bucket, we use the following CLI command (and this command works fine):

```
aws s3api put-object --grant-full-control id=e2cxxxxxxxxx --bucket my_bucket --key folder/filename --body filename
```

The `aws s3api` doesn't support uploading files > 5GB, which we will have to start supporting soon. I tried doing the upload using `aws s3` (the high level API) instead. The command now looks like:

```
aws s3 cp filename s3://my_bucket/folder/filename --grants full=id=e2cxxxxxxxxx
```

However, this command throws `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPart operation: Access Denied`

I'm trying to understand how the two are different and why one throws `AccessDenied` while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `s3api` set of commands is a 1:1 mapping with the low level [S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html).  The `s3` set of commands adds some higher level functionalities, like [syncing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) for example. To be able to do so, it often requires multiple API-level permissions.  So, behind the scene, a simple `aws s3 cp` command might use multiple low level APIs, and callers needs permissions for each of them.

You need to add all low level APIs in the 'Actions' section of the IAM policy.

There is no easy way to check what is the list of low level APIs used by a high level command. In your example, it looks like [UploadPart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html) is the missing one.  You should try to add it to the user/role/group policy and try again until you get all of them (`"Actions" : ["s3:Uploadpart", ...]`)
You can also try with a user having admin permission (`"Actions" : "s3:*"`) and configure Cloudtrail to analyse from the logs all the S3 APIs used by one specific command.

Comment: For details look here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/